# fixing an error i cannot spot in main() in C (stuck for hours on it - short program)

Tags: c, stdin

i'm having real hard time with my code, and my due date is today. i'm given an error "main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:186:7: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
       }". 
I've been trying for hours to play with the brackets and fix it but with no luck. i'm hoping you could help me fix it, as you are far more experienced than me.

it's basically a simple program that takes input from stdin(might be from keyboard or from a file using redirection) and applies the following:

1)puts a new line between sentences.
2)doesn't print numbers.
3)if inside a bracket, then letters must be capitalized(bold).
4)put's an uppercase on a first character of a sentence.
5)if not in a bracket nor in a beginning of a sentence, then it should make it a lowercase.

notes:
a)there's no limit on the length of the input, and each sentence can be written on several lines(the input).
b)if a dot (.) is inside a brackets, it doesn't make it a new sentence(no need to write a newline).
c)if two dots are given, then it's an empty sentence and should be written like the example.

basically, i just ask you to help me fix my code so it will run, as i've already done all of that(thought of i missed something and you can help me improve it - i will be very glad!)

example:

if given input:

i love to play hockey.. I NEED TO PLAY HOCKEY.. "hockey is life 3333".

the desired output will be:

I love to play hockey.

. I need to play hockey.

.

"HOCKEY IS LIFE"

the code in "temp.h" is:

```
#define go 0
#define endOfASentence 1
#define isAFirstQuotation 2
#define isASecondQuotation 3
#define inAQuotation 4
#define beginningOfSentence 5
#define middleOfSentence 6
```

the code in main program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "letters.h"

int checkIfLetter (char a); /*checking if char is a letter */
int checkIfnumber (char a); /*checking if char is a number */
int checkIfUpperCase (char a);  /*checking if char is upper case */
int checkIfLowerCase (char a);  /*checking if char is lower case */
int checkIfQuotation (char a);  /*check if char is a quotation */
int checkIfDot (char a);    /*check if char is a dot */





int
main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  int status = go;
  char a;
  int beginning = 0;        /*if beginning equals 0 it's the beginning of a sentence, if it's 1 then it's the middle of it */
  int secondQuote = 0;      /*if second quote equals 1, then it's inside of a quotation */
  while ((a = getchar ()) != EOF)
    {
      switch (status)
    {
    case go:
      if (a == '.')
        {
          status = endOfASentence;
        }
      else if (a == '"' && secondQuote == '0')
        {
          status = isAFirstQuotation;
        }
      else if (a == '"' && secondQuote == '1')
        {
          status = isASecondQuotation;
        }
      else if (checkIfLetter (a) == '1' && secondQuote == '1')
        {
          status = inAQuotation;
        }
      else if (checkIfnumber (a) == '1')
        {
          continue;
        }           /*a number should not be on the output, so we just ignore it and not using it */
      else if (checkIfLetter (a) == '1' && beginning == '0')
        {
          status = beginningOfSentence;
        }           /*i tried to differentiate between beginning and middle of the sentence using int beginning */
      else if (checkIfLetter (a) == '1' && beginning == '1')
        {
          status = middleOfSentence;
        }
    case beginningOfSentence:
      if (checkIfQuotation (a) && checkIfDot (a)
         && checkIfnumber (a) != 1)
        {
          if (checkIfUpperCase (a) == '1')
        {
          printf ("%c", toupper (a));
          beginning = 1;
          status = go;
        }
        } break;            /*set to upper and return to go */
    case middleOfSentence:
      if (checkIfQuotation (a) && checkIfDot (a)
         && checkIfnumber (a) != 1)
        {
          if (checkIfLowerCase (a) == '1')
          {
            printf ("%c", tolower (a));
            status = go;
          }
        } break;
    case endOfASentence:
          if (checkIfDot (a) == '1')
        {
          printf ("%c/n", a);
          beginning = 0;
          status = go;
        }break;     /*i tried to append(add) a new line after the dot and to set beginning to 0, to signify that after it's a beginning of a sentence */
    case isAFirstQuotation: /*if it's a quotation, continue to the next char and make it upper case as long as it's a lower case, until you get another quotation */
          while (checkIfLowerCase (a) == '1')
        {
          secondQuote == '1';
          status = go;
        }break;
    case isASecondQuotation:
          if (checkIfQuotation (a) == '1' && secondQuote == '1')
        {
          secondQuote = 0;
          status = go;
        }break;
    case inAQuotation:
          if (secondQuote == '1' && checkIfLetter (a) == '1')
        {
          printf ("%c", toupper (a));
          status = go;
        } break;
    }
    }
      return 0;
    }



  int checkIfLetter (char a)
  {
    if (isalpha (a))
      {
    return 1;
      }
    else
      {
    return 0;
      }
  }

    int checkIfnumber (char a)
    {
      if (isdigit (a))
    {
      return 1;
    }
      else
    {
      return 0;
    }
    }

    int checkIfUpperCase (char a)
    {
      if (checkIfLetter (a) == '1')
    {
      if (isupper (a))
        {
          return 1;
        }
      else
        {
          return 0;
        }
    }
    }

  int checkIfLowerCase (char a)
  {
    if (checkIfLetter (a) == '1')
      {
    if (islower (a))
      {
        return 1;
      }
    else
      {
        return 0;
      }
      }
  }

  int checkIfQuotation (char a)
  {
    if (a == '"')
      {
    return 1;
      }
    else
      {
    return 0;
      }
  }

  int checkIfDot (char a)
  {
    if (a == '.')
      {
    return 1;
      }
    else
      {
    return 0;
      }
  }
```

i don't know how to fix it and i've spent hours on it. would be very grateful if you could help.

i've tried to be very elaborative and to abide the rules

Comment: Indent please...

Comment: what do you mean? i used beautify on it before i posted

Comment: The error you get because of some parenthese issue//nothing else..

Comment: what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: And where is that famous line 187? Please mark it (I'm not going to count lines...)

Comment: exactly, it seems like there are parentheses missing in some places, and some additional ones where not neeeded. line 131, line 120, main method is not closed properly, better to use a editor like Microsoft code or something else to get some help on these

Comment: @coderredoc It does not matter because it is an awful code.:) It should be rewritten entirely.

Comment: I don't know what beautifier you have used..but really you should change the beautifier no matter what.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `break` statements after each `case` is done? It now just falls through.

Comment: I'll edit and add break; after each case. thank you very much. is there also another mistake? i can't even compile it yet

Comment: @BeginningMath.: Is this homework?

Comment: added break; and the given error points to the end of the code.

@coderredoc - yes, i've stated it in the question.

and to "vlad from moscow", it would be more helpful if you knew how to give concrete tips rather than what you chose to write, as it is not meaningful and doesn't help me solve the problem nor to code better.

Comment: You should have an even number of matching `{` and `}`. In **several** places you have 5 of those, where there should be 4 or 6. Start by fixing that, and then work on the warnings you will get when they match - like the difference between `0` and `'0'`, missing `;` after `break`, functions not always returning a value, and `getchar()` returning an `int`.

Comment: fixed the braces issue and added breaks, now it's running. can you give me concrete insights so i will be able to code better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to see if it produces the desired results.
Characters that are not letters, space, newline or dot are rejected at the top of the while and all letters are set to lower case.
Then the choice is to print one upper case letter at the start of the sentence or all upper case inside double quotes.
There are no breaks as oneUpper needs to fall through to allUpper. allUpper needs to fall through to default.
getchar returns an int so `int a` instead of `char a`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define oneUpper 1
#define allUpper 2

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int status = oneUpper;
    int a;
    while ( EOF != (a = getchar ()))
    {
        //discard non letter except space, newline and .
        if ( !isalpha ( a) && a != ' ' && a != '\"' && a != '.') {
            continue;
        }
        //set all to lower and let oneUpper or allUpper do the rest.
        a = tolower ( a);
        switch (status)
        {
            case oneUpper:
                if ( a == ' ' || a == '\n') {
                    putchar ( a);//print leading space and continue
                    continue;
                }
            case allUpper:
                a = toupper ( a);
            default:
                putchar ( a);
                if ( a == '\"') {
                    if ( status == allUpper) {
                        status = 0;//turn all upper off
                    }
                    else {
                        status = allUpper;//turn all upper on
                    }
                }
                if ( status == oneUpper) {
                    status = 0;//after printing one upper turn it off
                }
                if ( a == '.') {
                    if ( status != allUpper) {
                        putchar ( '\n');
                        status = oneUpper;//after a . turn one upper on
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so basically it's better to program without a lot of functions? could you please say what should i do better in the next times? it would help me understand all better

Comment: so in your program, how can i make sure that if a text in "" it will be bold? for instance if "kkk" the output will be "KKKKK"? and if a dot inside "" then it will still be there without new line, i.e "kkk.kkkk" willl be "KKK.KKKK"?  thank you very much for posting it and i'm trying to learn from it and your answers